# Scanf_s reading wrong input

Tags: c, printf, output, scanf

For this code below (in C)

```
    int small_a, small_b;
    printf("Please input two numbers\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &small_a, &small_b);
    printf("%d %d", &small_a, &small_b);
    int test_2nd = small_a - small_b;
    if (test_2nd < 0) {
        printf("a is smaller %d", &small_a);
    }
    else {
    printf("b is smaller %d", &small_b);
```

The values it prints when I write 4 and 2 is a huge six digit number (5504620 and 5504608 in this case) I don't understand where it goes wrong. `stdio.h` has been included as a header.

Comment: `printf("%d %d", &small_a, &small_b);` remove `&` --> `printf("%d %d", small_a, small_b);`

Comment: 1) check the returned value from any of the `scanf()` family of functions to assure the operation was successful.  2) when printing a variable, using `printf()` pass the actual variable, not the address of the variable.

Comment: Suggest you read the 'help' section on how to ask a question.  For instance when the question is about a run time problem, as your question is, post code that cleanly compiles, is small, and still shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in the print statement. In the code

```
 printf("%d %d", &small_a, &small_b);
```

you don't need (*want*) to take (*print*) the address. Remove that `&`.

That said, this actually  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `%d` with `printf()` expects an argument of type `int` and you're essentially supplying an `int *`, causing the UB.

FWIW, to print an address (pointer), you need to use `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void *`

Comment: The devil is in the details huh? I guess it's just been printing the address.

Comment: @Ansh Certainly. __God is in the detail__. double check always.